# Find numbers in a dataframe() greater than 5

Tags: r

How can I select numbers whose values are greater than 5? And how to determine which row and column are these numbers in? That is, how do I get a data frame like this

```
df = data.frame(
    co1 = c(5,9,6,1,6),
    co2 = c(8,5,4,6,2), 
    co3 = c(6,5,4,1,2),
    co4 = c(6,1,5,3,2),
    co5 = c(5,1,2,6,8))

rownames(df) = c("row1","row2","row3","row4","row5")

df
#      co1 co2 co3 co4 co5
# row1  5   8   6   6   5
# row2  9   5   5   1   1
# row3  6   4   4   5   2
# row4  1   6   1   3   6
# row5  6   2   2   2   8
```

Comment: Try with `which` i.e. `which(df > 5, arr.ind = TRUE)`

Comment: Your code doesn't run because it's missing some `c`s and a `)`. Adding whitespace makes it more obvious.

Comment: Would be useful to know what the expected output should look like. Also, what do you mean by "How do I get a dataframe like this" (isn't that the df you want to identify certain values in?)

Answer (score 0):

Just a tentative answer (since it is still rather unclear what you expect to get): assuming that you want to obtain a dataframe that records whether the values in the columns in your dataframe are, or aren't, > 5, you could run this `for` loop:

```
for(i in 1:ncol(df)){
  df[i] <- ifelse(df[i] > 5, "yes", "no")
}
df
  co1 co2 co3 co4 co5
1  no yes yes yes  no
2 yes  no  no  no  no
3 yes  no  no  no  no
4  no yes  no  no yes
5 yes  no  no  no yes
```

Is this what you wanted?

Comment: If you are going this route, then `df[] <- ifelse(df > 5, "yes", "no")` will suffice.  No loop necessary.

Comment: Thanks, that's useful.